# How to exclude files and directories from Notepad++ projects

Tags: notepad++

I'm just looking into Notepad++'s [project management features](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Project_Management). How can I ignore specific files and directories? (e.g. `__pycache__` and `*.pyc`)

[image]

Comment: If you change the folder properties to Hidden, it will be ignored unless you choose to include hidden folders. Very handy quick trick.

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot it looks that you used **Add Files from Directory...** from Project panel's context menu to add links to files. But that command leads you to directory picker dialog, not to file picker. Obviously, it gives you no control over what will be included so everything will be included.

But then you can

1. save the project workspace (what creates XML file)
2. open the file in Notepad++
3. mark `<file>` tags or entire `<folder>`...`</folder>` tags to exclude
4. delete marked lines
5. reload your project workspace from modified file

As you can probably see, all these items (project entries) do *not* dynamically mirror the file system, they are static links once created, regardless of how you added them into project. User interface allows you deletion only of single item at once since you cannot perform multi-select in the tree.  Therefore any selective exclusion you are asking about

1. if made from the UI, it is always manual by selectively adding items or by deleting items
2. can be made in mass way in workspace XML file which then needs to be manually reloaded

You might be able to automate this operation using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) but it is questionable whether it is worth the effort. You can also use Python script to dynamically update workspace XML file for you based on file system and desired exclusions, but whether it can achieve reloading is questionable (AutoHotKey still can).